# Enclosing DataRow ItemArray values in quotes

Tags: .net, string-concatenation, datarow

I am using a `String.Join` in order to concatenate and comma separate the values in my `DataRow` `ItemArray`. I am looking for an efficient way to double quote any of the array items that are of type `String`.

```
String.Join(",", dr.ItemArray())

Whitesnake,Motley Crue,1987,Tour,75000 

"Whitesnake","Motley Crue",1987,"Tour",75000 (The desired format)
```

How do I best accomplish this?

Comment: Some reviewer who comes along is going to find "efficient way" questions as subjective. See : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Linq projection to add quotes to string values:

```
var items = dr.ItemArray.Select (i => i is string ? "\"" + i + "\"" : i);
var line  = string.Join(",",items);
```

or in VB:

```
Dim items = dr.ItemArray.Select(Function(i) If(TypeOf i Is String, """" + i + """", i.ToString()))
Dim line = String.Join(",", items)
```